# ZK HTTP 501 - Service unimplemented

Tags: internet-explorer, http, weblogic-10.x, zk

I'm using `ZK 5.0.3 Framework + IE 9 + Weblogic 10.3`. On my UI, I get HTTP 501 service unimplemented error randomly. I've verified the code and nothing suspicious found. When I intercepted the HTTP messages between IE and Weblogic using Fiddler, found that there were garbage characters prepended to the POST method. Here's a sample intercepted RAW HTTP message sent by UI to back end.

```
ERROR: 22%3A0%2C%22LEFT%22%3A160%7D&CMD2=ONSCROLLPOS&UUID2=UQ0Q2R&DATA2=%7B%22TOP%22%3A0
%2C%22LEFT%22%3A2948%7D&CMD3=ONCLICK&UUID3=UQ0Q1R&DATA3=%7B%22PAGEX%22%3A360%2C%22PAGEY%22%3A225%2C%22WHICH%22%3A1%2C%22X%22%3A5%2C%22Y%22%3A-3%7DPOST 
httpurl://192.168.4.169:7001/DPQA13/zkau HTTP/1.1 Accept: / Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 ZK-SID: 2331 Referer: httpurl://192.168.4.169:7001/DPQA13
/DP/home.zul Accept-Language: en-in Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET 
CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BRI/2) Host: 192.168.4.169:7001 Content-Length: 136 Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache Cookie: 
JSESSIONID=D9TTRnFR8DyWpGc84cQZxVW1Gx7K0Z14kKRKsDQmntr9zSkZtYk8!-1480174431


dtid=zwvb&cmd0=onClick&uuid0=iBJQ7i&data0=%7B%22pageX%22%3A558%2C%22pageY%22%3A283
%2C%22which%22%3A1%2C%22x%22%3A31%2C%22y%22%3A4%7D
```

Interestingly, the ZK library has a retry mechanism which retries the HTTP communication if there's a 5xx error code. However, when it retries for the second time, it does send the correct HTTP method, no garbage characters prepended. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I doubt this is ZK issue. Have you tried deploying the same app to tomcat or jetty and reproduce this issue?

Comment: i haven't tried with tomcat but with Websphere 7. Another interesting thing is, this is reproducible only on one of the machines with Windows 7 here. Other windows 7 machines with same IE 9 version don't reproduce the problem. So I think this must be IE + ZK specific issue. Here I'm mentioning ZK again because somehow it is not able to cope up this particular machine only. We also tried changing the compatibility version to 7 and 8, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was an environment issue.
Yesterday, we did narrow down the problem and found out the actual cause. We were using IE Version: 9.0.8112.16421 - Update Versions: 9.0.6 (KB2675157) which was producing this defect. We tried on another Windows machine with IE Version: 9.0.8112.16421 - Update Versions: 9.0.15 (KB2817183) and it ran smoothly. It was clear that the 9.0.6 had some problem and so we upgraded it with "Automatic Updates On". As it got upgraded to 9.0.15 (KB2817183), the problem disappeared.